# Screenshot problem in Kivy/python application on raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, kivy, screenshot

I am trying to take a screenshot of the lines drawn in my Kivy paint app. I have tried the following three ways but none have worked.

```
self.export_to_png('image_1.png')
ImageGrab.grab_to_file('image_2.png')
self.screenshot('image_3.png')
```

Export_to_png produces the following image:

[image]

ImageGrab produces a printscreen of what is underneath the kivy app:

[image]

I couldn't figure out the syntax to execute the screenshot function, so it just produces an error:

```
AttributeError: 'Screenshot' object has no attribute 'screenshot'
```

Python File:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Line
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen , ScreenManager

import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab

class Home(Screen):
    pass

class DrawInput(Widget):

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        with self.canvas:
            touch.ud["line"] = Line(points=(touch.x, touch.y))           

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        touch.ud["line"].points += (touch.x, touch.y)

    def clear_canvas(self):
        self.canvas.clear()

class Screenshot(Widget):   

    def take(self):
        self.export_to_png('image_1.png')
        ImageGrab.grab_to_file('image_2.png')
        self.screenshot('image_3.png')  

class SimpleKivy(App):
    def build(self):
        return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    SimpleKivy().run()
```

Kivy File:

```
<Button>:
    font_size: 40
    color: 1,1,1,1

ScreenManager:

    Home:

        name: 'home'
        DrawInput:
            id: widget_clear

        Screenshot:
            id: widget_screenshot

        FloatLayout:

            Button:
                text: "Clear"
                pos_hint: {"x": 0, 'top': 0.6666}
                size_hint: 0.2, 0.3333
                on_release: 
                    widget_clear.clear_canvas()

            Button:
                text: "Save"
                pos_hint: {"x": 0.8, 'top': 0.6666}
                size_hint: 0.2, 0.3333
                on_release:
                    widget_screenshot.take()
                    widget_clear.clear_canvas()
```

I am using Raspbian 9.4, Python 2.7.13 and Kivy 1.10.1.

Comment: Have you tried if you get the same result on your PC?

Comment: I have not, the final application has to run on a pi unfortunately. So I hope taking a screenshot is not limited with the pi

Comment: My idea with my question is to rule out that the problem is the raspberry, if the code works on your PC then the problem is the rpi, if it does not work the problem is your code, so the solution will be in theory easier to discover, so I ask you to do the test on your PC first.

Comment: I will attempt it on pc tomorrow and see if the pi is the problem

Comment: I have figured a solution to this, I stopped using the HDMI out on my pi and instead used the raspberry pi touchscreen. Using export_to_PNG seems to work fine in this setting.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following ways.,

1. Window.screenshot() API
2. widget.export_to_png() or export_as_image().save(filename)
   but couldn't able to take screenshot in the test setup. (raspberry pi with LCD display).

Try building `scrot` command into the Linux image and invoking `scrot` using `subprocess` module. This worked in our setup.